# this2.$dispatch is not a function

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm trying to use the dispatch function in vue.js like this.
But I'm getting an error saying this2.$dispatch is not a function...like you can see on the screenshot

**message.vue**

```
  export default {
    data(){
        return{
            message:'',
            isLoading:false,
        }
    },

    methods:{
        addMessage(){
            if(this.message !=''){
                this.sendData();
            } else{
                this.$fire({
                    title: "Error",
                    text: "Enter some text.",
                    type: "error",
                    timer: 3000
                }).then(r => {
                    console.log(r.value);
                });
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.isLoading = false
                },700)
            }
        },
        sendData(){
            this.isLoading = true;
            this.$http.post('/add-message' , {message:this.message, id_rooms:this.$route.params.id_rooms}).then((response) => {
                console.log(response.json());
                if(response.body != 'Error'){
                    this.message = '';
                    this.$dispatch('new_message', response.json());
                } else{
                    this.isLoading = false;
                }
            }, (response) =>{

            });
        }
    }
}
```

and then I'm trying to get it out like this

**chat.vue**

```
 export default {
        components:{
            get_message:getMessage,
            add_message:addMessage,
        },
        data(){
            return{
                messages:[]
            }

        },
        events:{
            'new_message':function(data){
                this.messages.push(data);
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm facing this error in console...any ideas how can I solve this ?

[image]

Comment: can you give more context of how you're calling `this.$dispatch('new_message', response.json());`?

Comment: Most commonly this is because you are using `this` but it's not actually the context you expect (e.g. you're using it in an event handler and it's the element context rather than the component context). We can't know that for sure though unless we know how you're using that

Comment: @Daniel I updated my code

Comment: did you try `this.$store.dispatch('new_message', response.json());`? I don't know what `this.$dispatch` does, but I haven't come across that before.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, I tried...now there is an error app.js:1980 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Comment: what library are you using for `this.$http`? And does `$dispatch` work if you use it outside the promise?

Comment: @Daniel https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

Comment: I looked through the code for references to `call`, having found some, I think it's possible that even when using an arrow function, the scope is changed. I've updated answer to with options to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

#### update

If your store is registered with Vue, it seems like it should work. If your `$dispatch` works outside of the promise, you can try storing `this` context in another variable

```js
sendData(){
    this.isLoading = true;
    const that = this;
    this.$http
        .post('/add-message' , {message:this.message, id_rooms:this.$route.params.id_rooms})
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.json());
            if(response.body != 'Error'){
                that.message = '';
                that.$dispatch('new_message', response.json());
            } else{
                that.isLoading = false;
            }
        }, (response) =>{

        });
}
```

or just the `$dispatch`

```js
sendData(){
    this.isLoading = true;
    const $dispatch = this.$dispatch;
    this.$http
        .post('/add-message' , {message:this.message, id_rooms:this.$route.params.id_rooms})
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.json());
            if(response.body != 'Error'){
                this.message = '';
                $dispatch('new_message', response.json());
            } else{
                this.isLoading = false;
            }
        }, (response) =>{

        });
}
```

---

Taking a guess here, but try calling this instead

```js
this.$store.dispatch('new_message', response.json());
```

alternatively, your issue could be a scope issue (seeing that this is called from a promise)

if you have a function declared like this in the promise handler `then(function(response){this.$store.dispatch('new_message', response.json());})` it might be due to scope

instead you could try using arrow function

```js
then((response) => {
  this.$store.dispatch('new_message', response.json());
})
```